# Declaring the 'AND' condition in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please tell me if this isn't the right way to approach the problem.

I want to declare the code after my AND condition in a variable.. the code is:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Key = '12345'
AND (Condition1 or Condition2 or Condition3)
```

I am hoping to achieve something like this:

```
DECLARE @Condition
SET @Condition = 'Condition1 or Condition2 or Condition3'

SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Key = '12345'
AND @Condition
```

The `AND` operator expects a boolean expresssion so this doesn't work. Please tell me how I can achieve this..

The idea is that I can store the `@Condition` in a variable table `(varName, varValue)` and fetch it from there whenever I want to use it in the code (kinda like a global variable). Please also let me know if the performance of the code will be affected if I follow this approach.

Comment: This is probably not the right way to approach the problem; on the other hand, you haven't told us what the problem **is**.. Can you explain what your overall goal is? "Dynamic SQL" is the name of what you want to do, and yes, it does have performance (and maintenance) implications.

Comment: I want to make the @Condition a global variable so that I can reference them from any procedure/code. The Condition is constant and doesn't change so I don't have to do any updates to the variable.

Comment: Ok, but [why](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/01/22.html)? Global variables are widely considered a Bad Idea. They lead to spaghetti code. What is the problem you're trying to solve with a global variable?

Comment: I have to write multiple rules to filter transactions and more than one rule references the same conditions..So that, in case these conditions change, I can just update the one table

Comment: If the condition is constant, you could just define a view like `create view MyConditions as select * from MyTable where (Condition1 or Condition2 or Condition3)` - then you can say `select * from MyConditions where Key = '12345'`.

Comment: So, I can create views or use dynamic sql or create a table with the conditions.. also, i can hardcode values as is.. can you please tell me how the performance will be affected in each case? The database handles high volume of transactions so I don't want to slow it down..

Comment: The only way to be sure is to test it. My prediction: hardcoding in each place will likely be the fastest, extremely closely followed by the view. The dynamic SQL options will incur a little penalty, but not a lot unless you're running this SQL 10 times a second.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dynamic sql:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'select * from mytable where [key] = @key and @condition';
set @sql = replace(@sql, '@condition', @condition);

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@key varchar(255)', @key = '12345';
```

When you put `@condition` in the `where` clause it is treated as a string.  That's all.  No semantic analysis.

Comment: I don't know what your performance constraints are; you really need to test on your system.  There is a little additional overhead for dynamic SQL, but probably not much compared to running the query directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you can create a table variable with your conditions... Since you're not very specific about what those conditions are, it's hard to tell if something like this would work, but this is an approach I sometimes use:

```
declare @conditions table (condition nvarchar(255), value bit);
insert into @table (condition, value)
select condition, value
from (
    values ('Less than x', 1), ('Greater than y', 0))
) x (condition, value)
```

Then use that in your where clause...

```
select *
from Table
where not exists (select 1 from @conditions where value = 1)
```

Or you can join onto it. If you are comparing ints, you could cross join and say `where @conditions.condition < yourTable.value`.

Comment: If I create an actual table and refer the table in my code, will it affect the performance? Compared to hardcoding the values?

Comment: Well, hardcoding the values in the query will be the fastest (as long as they're not variables, but values written in the where clause) and especially so if the table is properly indexed. But querying from an "actual" table (if by which you mean a real, regular database table - not a temp table, or table variable) is always going to give you better performance than a temporary (or variable) table. My impression was that you wanted to do these comparisons on the fly, but if this is re-usable, then hardcoded values or a real table is the way to go.

Comment: And further, unless you're dealing with very many rows, the addition of a join onto an indexed table is going to be a very negligible performance hit. Organizing the database for clarity and flexibility for your application code will save much more time overall than the extra couple milliseconds you might see here.